# Calculate $\int_\gamma \frac{\cos z}{z}dz, \int_\gamma \frac{\sin z}{z}dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Calculate the following integrals
$$
I_1=\int_\gamma \frac{\cos z}{z}dz, \ \ \ \ \ I_2=\int_\gamma \frac{\sin z}{z}dz
$$
with:

1) $\gamma$ circle of radius 1 centered at the origin,

2) $\gamma$ circle of radius 1 centered in $z=5i$,

For $I_1$, and apllying residue theorem, we have: 1) $I_1=2\pi i$, 2) $I_1=0$ because pole $z_0=0$ isn't in circle of radius 1 centered in $z=5i$. Is that so? I have some dubt for $I_2$. Can I apply residue theorem? What is the pole?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You don't really need the full power of the residue theorem for this, you can use Cauchy's theorem when the singularity isn't inside the contour (to get answer 0 immediately) and Cauchy's integral theorem when it lies inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1)-(2) Look fine, and for $\;I_2\;$ there's no pole but a removable singularity since

$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\sin z}z=1\;\ldots$$